# How to run debian.iso on Windows using qemu?

Tags: linux, windows, debian, virtualization, qemu

I have debian.iso + windows 7 and qemu. I don't know windows absolutely. How can I run debian.iso using qemu? What command I need to use for running debian?

Comment: have you looked at a QEMU documentation or wiki?

Comment: no. i bad speak English. I can't read ((

Comment: Yet your profile and other questions say otherwise.  marking the question for closure.